# finding the section of a PE's entrypoint

Tags: portable-executable

I'm trying to find what section the PE entrypoint points to.
I have two questions:

1. Is it correct to say that this section is the one such that section.PointerToRawData < AddressOfEntryPoint < section.PointerToRawData + section.SizeOfRawData ?
2. I see some PE's that have AddressOfEntryPoint > total size of file. How is this possible? Is the AddressOfEntryPoint value wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that this section is the one such that
>   section.PointerToRawData < AddressOfEntryPoint <
>   section.PointerToRawData + section.SizeOfRawData ?

Not quite, the section you want should be the one such that: section.**VirtualAddress** < AddressOfEntryPoint < section.**VirtualAddress**+ section.**VirtualSize**

Then to find the position in the file, use: AddressOfEntryPoint - section.VirtualAddress + section.PointerToRawData